# Can jwPlayer access a UDP multicast stream?

Tags: video-streaming, jwplayer, vlc

I am newbie in video streaming (still trying to understand what is involved in streaming live video).

We are currently using the VLC Web Plugin in IE to access a multicast UDP live stream sent from our hardware encoder as udp://@224.2.2.2:1000.

We are looking at JWPlayer and I have seen links where others talk about RTP streams.

Will JwPlayer work by setting the url path to udp://@224.2.2.2:1000?

Comment: AFAIK, JW Player supports only HLS and RTMP streaming. No UDP. See http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/topics/564477-streaming/articles

Comment: Correct, UDP is not supported.